# find_or_create_by multiple attributes not finding records when called in context of belongs_to object (AR bug in 2.3.11?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am adding omniauth to a rails 2.3.11 application with devise. I'm basically following Ryan Bate's [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) (with appropriate modifications for rails 2.3). But I'm seeing something very odd in testing this part of the code:

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    current_user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
    redirect_to authentications_url
  end

  ...
end
```

The find_or_create always creates. In the log, I see this select:

```
SELECT * FROM `authentications` WHERE (`authentications`.`provider` IN ('facebook','XXXXXXX') AND `authentications`.`uid` IS NULL) AND ((`authentications`.`user_id` = 10)) LIMIT 1
```

That is not the right select for that method. auth['provider'] and auth['uid'] are populated correctly (and it creates the new record just fine).

More perplexing: If I go into the console and do `Authentication.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid('facebook', 'XXXXX')`, it works fine (it finds the existing record). But if I get a user and do `user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid('facebook', 'XXXXX')`, it creates a new record and I see the same problematic query statement in the log.

I know I can work around this (and Ryan Bates changes this code later anyway), but this is very troubling. Am I missing something or does this look like a bug in ActiveRecord?

This is not specific to OmniAuth or Devise. Before submitting this, I tried it with two other classes (rather simple classes). Same result [ Klass.find_or_create_by_a_and_b('A','B') works but parent.klasses.find_or_create_by_a_and_b('A','B') generates a select that wants b to be null and a in ('A','B')].

Now I'm definitely thinking this is a bug 2.3.11. Before I submit a bug, does anybody see anything I'm missing? Has anyone seen this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Submit it to the rails project.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated an app from Rails 2.3.10 to 2.3.11 and I ran into this bug, too.

In our code, we have:

```
      rate_plan = lodging.rate_plans.find_or_create_by_primary_code_and_secondary_code(rate_plan_code, inv_type_code)
```

which worked fine under 2.3.10.  Under 2.3.11, rate_plan winds up being a new record, even though find_by_primary_code_and_secondary_code(rate_plan_code, inv_type_code) will find an existing record.  Not only is rate_plan a new record in 2.3.11, but it's not saved because our uniqueness validation isn't met.

Ugh.  I'll go back to 2.3.10 for now.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of auth['provider'] and auth['uid']?
Maybe I am wrong, but it looks to me that auth['provider'] is ['facebook','XXXXXXX'] and auth['uid'] is nil.

Answer (score 0):

It definetely must be, like Tudor Constantin says, a problem with the auth['provider'] value, as it seems to be an array. Have you tried to make a puts call over this variable? What is the result?

Also I hope that you know that this:

> Authentication.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid('facebook', 'XXXXX')

is not the same as this:

> user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid('facebook', 'XXXXX')

In the first case you're searching through *all* Authentication instances / rows, while in the second one you're reducing the search scope so it *only* looks for Authentication instances / rows that belong to that concrete instance of User.

Comment: No. Re-read the post (and the comment from a user experiencing the same problem). auth['provider'] is not an array (I verified its value, of course--and it were an array, it wouldn't work in the non-scoped find either, but it does). Moreover, look at the code I entered into the console, and the pseudo-code from the simplified example I tried. Those are specifying string literals. Definitely no arrays there! (And of course I know the difference between the two finds; that should be obvious from the post.) At this point, I'm sure this is a bug in 2.3.11 AR.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
auth['uid']
```

I guess it is coming blank for you. That is why

```
`authentications`.`uid` IS NULL) AND ((`authentications`.`user_id` = 10))
```

is conflicting